# How to delete columns in numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to delete selected columns in a numpy.array . This is what I do:

```
n [397]: a = array([[ NaN,   2.,   3., NaN],
   .....:        [  1.,   2.,   3., 9]])

In [398]: print a
[[ NaN   2.   3.  NaN]
 [  1.   2.   3.   9.]]

In [399]: z = any(isnan(a), axis=0)

In [400]: print z
[ True False False  True]

In [401]: delete(a, z, axis = 1)
Out[401]:
 array([[  3.,  NaN],
       [  3.,   9.]])
```

In this example my goal is to delete all the columns that contain NaN's. I expect the last command 
to result in:

```
array([[2., 3.],
       [2., 3.]])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Given its name, I think the standard way should be `delete`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.delete(A, 1, 0)  # delete second row of A
B = np.delete(B, 2, 0)  # delete third row of B
C = np.delete(C, 1, 1)  # delete second column of C
```

According to [numpy's documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), the parameters for `numpy.delete` are as follow:

`numpy.delete(arr, obj, axis=None)`

- `arr` refers to the input array,
- `obj` refers to which sub-arrays (e.g. column/row no. or slice of the array) and
- `axis` refers to either column wise (`axis = 1`) or row-wise (`axis = 0`) delete operation.

Comment: I believe you should be referencing `numpy`, not `scipy`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: just add explanation: array, index and axis as parameters

Answer (score 33):

Example from [the numpy documentation](http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-a2ab8bc7283d245977d250a5d8761f9369d0a60e):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
               [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
               [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
               [12, 13, 14, 15]])

>>> numpy.delete(a, numpy.s_[1:3], axis=0)                       # remove rows 1 and 2

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

>>> numpy.delete(a, numpy.s_[1:3], axis=1)                       # remove columns 1 and 2

array([[ 0,  3],
       [ 4,  7],
       [ 8, 11],
       [12, 15]])
```

Comment: @alvas here is a well-organized explanation! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682754/np-delete-and-np-s-whats-so-special-about-np-s

Comment: @Alvas , s_ is: `A nicer way to build up index tuples for arrays.`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html

Answer (score 16):

Another way is to use masked arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ np.nan,   2.,   3., np.nan], [  1.,   2.,   3., 9]])
print(a)
# [[ NaN   2.   3.  NaN]
#  [  1.   2.   3.   9.]]
```

The np.ma.masked_invalid method returns a masked array with nans and infs masked out:

```
print(np.ma.masked_invalid(a))
[[-- 2.0 3.0 --]
 [1.0 2.0 3.0 9.0]]
```

The np.ma.compress_cols method returns a 2-D array with any column containing a 
masked value suppressed:

```
a=np.ma.compress_cols(np.ma.masked_invalid(a))
print(a)
# [[ 2.  3.]
#  [ 2.  3.]]
```

See 
[manipulating-a-maskedarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#manipulating-a-maskedarray)

Answer (score 9):

This creates another array without those columns:

```
  b = a.compress(logical_not(z), axis=1)
```

Comment: cool. I wish matlab's syntax worked here: "a(:,z) = []" is much simpler

Comment: @bpowah: indeed. the more general way would be b = a[:,z]. You might want to update your answer accordingly

Answer (score 8):

From [Numpy Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)

np.delete(arr, obj, axis=None)
    Return a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> np.delete(arr, 1, 0)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

>>> np.delete(arr, np.s_[::2], 1)
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 6,  8],
       [10, 12]])
>>> np.delete(arr, [1,3,5], None)
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Answer (score 6):

In your situation, you can extract the desired data with:

```
a[:, -z]
```

"-z" is the logical negation of the boolean array "z". This is the same as:

```
a[:, logical_not(z)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A = array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
               [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
               [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

>>> A = A.transpose()

>>> A = A[1:].transpose()
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing Matrix columns that contain NaN.
This is a lengthy answer, but hopefully easy to follow.

```
def column_to_vector(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
import numpy
def remove_NaN_columns(matrix):
    import scipy
    import math
    from numpy import column_stack, vstack

    columns = A.shape[1]
    #print("columns", columns)
    result = []
    skip_column = True
    for column in range(0, columns):
        vector = column_to_vector(A, column)
        skip_column = False
        for value in vector:
            # print(column, vector, value, math.isnan(value) )
            if math.isnan(value):
                skip_column = True
        if skip_column == False:
            result.append(vector)
    return column_stack(result)

### test it
A = vstack(([ float('NaN'), 2., 3., float('NaN')], [ 1., 2., 3., 9]))
print("A shape", A.shape, "\n", A)
B = remove_NaN_columns(A)
print("B shape", B.shape, "\n", B)

A shape (2, 4) 
 [[ nan   2.   3.  nan]
 [  1.   2.   3.   9.]]
B shape (2, 2) 
 [[ 2.  3.]
 [ 2.  3.]]
```

Comment: I actually don't follow you. How does this code work?