# np.delete and np.s_. What's so special about np_s?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, indexing, slice, delete-row

I don't really understand why regular indexing can't be used for np.delete.  What makes np.s_ so special?

For example with this code, used to delete the some of the rows of this array..

```
inlet_names = np.delete(inlet_names, np.s_[1:9], axis = 0)
```

Why can't I simply use regular indexing and do..

```
inlet_names = np.delete(inlet_names, [1:9], axis = 0)
```

or

```
inlet_names = np.delete(inlet_names, inlet_names[1:9], axis = 0)
```

From what I can gather, np.s_ is the same as np.index_exp except it doesn't return a tuple, but both can be used anywhere in Python code.

Then when I look into the np.delete function, it indicates that you can use something like `[1,2,3]` to delete those specific indexes along the entire array.  So whats preventing me from using something similar to delete certain rows or columns from the array?

I'm simply assuming that this type of indexing is read as something else in np.delete so you need to use np.s_ in order to specify, but I can't get to the bottom of what exactly it would be reading it as because when I try the second piece of code it simply returns "invalid syntax". Which is weird because this code works...

```
inlet_names = np.delete(inlet_names, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], axis = 0)
```

So I guess the answer could possibly be that np.delete only accepts a list of the indexes that you would like to delete. And that np._s returns a list of the indexes that you specify for the slice.

Just could use some clarification and some corrections on anything I just said about the functions that may be wrong, because a lot of this is just my take, the documents don't exactly explain everything that I was trying to understand. I think I'm just overthinking this, but I would like to actually understand it, if someone could explain it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`np.delete` is not doing anything unique or special.  It just returns a copy of the original array with some items missing.  Most of the code just interprets the inputs in preparation to make this copy.

What you are asking about is the `obj` parameter

> obj : slice, int or array of ints

In simple terms, `np.s_` lets you supply a slice using the familiar `:` syntax.  The `x:y` notation cannot be used as a function parameter.

Let's try your alternatives (you allude to these in results and errors, but they are buried in the text):

```
In [213]: x=np.arange(10)*2   # some distinctive values

In [214]: np.delete(x, np.s_[3:6])
Out[214]: array([ 0,  2,  4, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

So `delete` with `s_` removes a range of values, namely `6 8 10`, the 3rd through 5th ones.

```
In [215]: np.delete(x, [3:6])
  File "<ipython-input-215-0a5bf5cc05ba>", line 1
    np.delete(x, [3:6])
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why the error?  Because `[3:4]` is an indexing expression.  `np.delete` is a function.  Even `s_[[3:4]]` has problems.  `np.delete(x, 3:6)` is also bad, because Python only accepts the `:` syntax in an indexing context, where it automatically translates it into a `slice` object.  Note that is is a `syntax error`, something that the interpreter catches before doing any calculations or function calls.

```
In [216]: np.delete(x, slice(3,6))
Out[216]: array([ 0,  2,  4, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

A `slice` works instead of `s_`; in fact that is what `s_` produces

```
In [233]: np.delete(x, [3,4,5])
Out[233]: array([ 0,  2,  4, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

A list also works, though it works in different way (see below).

```
In [217]: np.delete(x, x[3:6])
Out[217]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 14, 18])
```

This works, but produces are different result, because `x[3:6]` is not the same as `range(3,6)`.  Also the `np.delete` does not work like the `list` delete.  It deletes by index, not by matching value.

`np.index_exp` fails for the same reason that `np.delete(x, (slice(3,6),))` does.  `1`, `[1]`, `(1,)` are all valid and remove one item.  Even `'1'`, the string, works.  `delete` parses this argument, and at this level, expects something that can be turned into an integer.  `obj.astype(intp)`.  `(slice(None),)` is not a slice, it is a 1 item tuple.  So it's handled in a different spot in the `delete` code.  This is `TypeError` produced by something that `delete` calls, very different from the `SyntaxError`.  In theory `delete` could extract the slice from the tuple and proceed as in the `s_` case, but the developers did not choose to consider this variation.

A quick study of the code shows that `np.delete` uses 2 distinct copying methods - by slice and by boolean mask.  If the `obj` is a slice, as in our example, it does (for 1d array):

```
out = np.empty(7)
out[0:3] = x[0:3]
out[3:7] = x[6:10]
```

But with `[3,4,5]` (instead of the slice) it does:

```
keep = np.ones((10,), dtype=bool)
keep[[3,4,5]] = False
return x[keep]
```

Same result, but with a different construction method.  `x[np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],bool)]` does the same thing.

In fact boolean indexing or masking like this is more common than `np.delete`, and generally just as powerful.

---

From the `lib/index_tricks.py` source file:

```
index_exp = IndexExpression(maketuple=True)
s_ = IndexExpression(maketuple=False)
```

They are slighly different versions of the same thing.  And both are just convenience functions.

```
In [196]: np.s_[1:4]
Out[196]: slice(1, 4, None)
In [197]: np.index_exp[1:4]
Out[197]: (slice(1, 4, None),)
In [198]: np.s_[1:4, 5:10]
Out[198]: (slice(1, 4, None), slice(5, 10, None))
In [199]: np.index_exp[1:4, 5:10]
Out[199]: (slice(1, 4, None), slice(5, 10, None))
```

The `maketuple` business applies only when there is a single item, a slice or index.