# Delete row from 2D array python (IndexError)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got one 2-D array

`data = [[1,2,3...], [4,5,6...], [7,8,9...], ...]`

and another 1-D array which contains the MINIMUM value of each sub-array from above:

`minima= [1, 4, 7, ....]`. So consequently `len(minima) = len(data)`.

Now i want to set a threshold value, say `threshold = 7` and want to delete each sub-array of `data` with a minimum below this threshold. So I tried the following:

```
threshold = 7
for i in range(len(minima)):
    if minima[i] < threshold:
        data = np.delete(data, i, 1)
```

but this gives me an IndexError:
IndexError: index 225 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 225

I guess it has sth to do with the axis and a loop is not the best approach but my expertise is very limited. Appreciate your help!

Comment: An (overly?) detailed explanation as to why 'delete` (even in a list) is dangerous in a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013951/how-to-use-delete-to-delete-specific-array-in-numpy-when-iterate-it/61015621#61015621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this will fail is because if you delete a row, then the number of rows declreases, but `i` will keep incrementing until the "*old*" number of rows.

But anyway, using a loop to each time delete one row is not very *efficient*. Numpy can boost efficiency by doing operations in *bulk*. By iterating, your algorithm will likely not be much faster than a simply Python program without using numpy.

You can just filter the array, with:

```
data2 = data[minima >= threshold]
```

Note that you do not need to calculate the row-wise minimum yourself, you can calculate this with:

```
data2 = data[data.min(axis=1) >= threshold]
```